# How to handle multiple save states on mobile?

Tags: save, accounts, multiple-data

I have a mobile app that I am working on that allows an account owner to manage subscribers on the account. From one screen, they will be able to set "limits" using a slider on the account. Each input/action from the account owner is a service call.

The initial UI was a batch edit and save mode where all the changes are made and one service call is made. The issue with this flow is that since everything is its own call, some elements could potentially fail and some pass which would mean multiple success/alert notifications at a time.

So the alternative is a save state for each individual subscriber where we force the user to pay attention to each individual save to make a change.

[image]

Does anyone know of a better experience in this case?

Comment: Is there a reason why changes should explicitly be saved individually?

Comment: My initial mock was a batch save but we realized that each action would be a service call which could mean that in an account, there could be anywhere from three service calls up to 15 calls depending on the scenario with the potential of some calls succeeding and some failing. So the issue becomes how do we handle so many alert/notifications without degrading the user experience. The individual save mitigates the risk to one or two action items per sub.

Comment: Why is each action its own service call? Are these settings for 3rd party services?

Comment: we are accessing services that a somewhat 3rd party and have certain limitations to them.

Answer (score 1):

Send a **single notification** explaining that "some" settings could not be saved, and point them to the *first* one in line. The user will then scroll down for the rest in line and find them naturally. On larger screens, you have more options to provide a helper box which lists all failed sections and highlight them with a light shade of red.

This will work better with a single "Save" button at the end, but for multiple "Save" buttons (if you *have* to), show inline error messages as the user would expect an immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

Add a default filter (ala *) for everyone and then a filter change for selection narrowing of subscribers to set limits based on filter data.
Last is per subscriber info/profile where it can be changed individually.

Basically one bulk and individual ones in the details.